# What is the most efficient way to read lines from files stored on HDFS in Python?

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to figure out a way to read lines of data from multiple text files stored on HDFS server, in Python.
I need to parse each line and keep only part of the data, so I prefer not to save the files locally.

I need a way to connect to the server, go over all files in a specific folder and from each file read all lines and perform an (irrelevant to this question) action on them.

Comment: If you need to read every line of any file you're interested in anyway, what does multiple tiny network requests gain you over two (one each way) larger ones?

Comment: The question is which two larger requests should I make? I'm trying to decide on the best package to use for it

Comment: Google search throws up this: https://github.com/traviscrawford/python-hdfs/blob/master/example.py

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it should work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub repository mentioned in the comments to the question, python-hdfs, queries HDFS from Python through libhdfs, the C interface to HDFS. Recently, WebHDFS was introduced, which provides a REST interface to HDFS. https://github.com/drelu/webhdfs-py is a Python client for WebHDFS, and is likely a better choice than python-hdfs.

Comment: "is likely a better choice than python-hdfs." Why?

Comment: Because the REST interface was implemented recently and is more actively maintained. Also, it does not require the additional build complexity of the C client, and it uses a plain text protocol, which in theory is easier to debug when things go awry.

Answer (score 1):

The pythonic way to do it would be to use itertools.chain.  But you can write a small utility generator function which iterates over files and then iterates over lines in the files and yields one line at a time.  Something like this:

```
def lines_in_files(connection):
    for f in # some code which fetches a files at a time from the connection
         for line in f:
             yield line
```

If your fetched file object doesn't support all the file methods, wrap its contents in StringIO before doing `for line in`.